# DataGridView Multiple Column Sort in VB.NET Not Working

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` control that contains a list of players, along with how many games they've played, won, lost, their win percentage, and high score. I know the control can only sort by a single column by default, but I found a piece of code that seems like it should work, but it's not populating my control with the data afterwards.

Here is the code I've implemented into my program:

```
' Style the DataGridView table and customise sorting by PERC, WON and then HIGH

    With frmHighscores
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        table.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("P", GetType(Integer))
        table.Columns.Add("W", GetType(Integer))
        table.Columns.Add("L", GetType(Integer))
        table.Columns.Add("%", GetType(Decimal))
        table.Columns.Add("High", GetType(Integer))

        For l = 0 To 9
            table.Rows.Add(LNAME(l), PLAYED(l), WON(l), LOST(l), PERC(l), HIGH(l))
        Next

        table.DefaultView.Sort = "% Desc, W Desc, High Desc"
        .dgvHighscores.DataSource = table

    End With
```

As you can see, I create a table, sort it by 3 columns, and then try to bind it to my control as the datasource, but the control just displays empty cells; no data. The arrays `LNAME()`, `PLAYED()`, `WON()`, `LOST()`, `PERC()` and `HIGH()` all contain the data as the same data types as defined in the table. I used them originally to add rows directly to the control before I tried using this multi-sort but the data is not displayed.

What have I done wrong here? Why is the DataGridView control not displaying the data after I set `table` as the datasource?

EDIT: image added

[image: DataGridView object named dgvHighscores]

Sorry about the poor image quality.

Comment: A `List(Of Player)` would make everything easier and simpler compared to multiple parallel arrays.  Use it as the DataSource, then just sort it as you want using `Player.OrderByDecending(Function (p) p.Played).ThenByDescending(Functon (w) w.Wins).ThenByDescending(Function (q) q.High)`

Comment: My guess is that "%" is not considered a valid identifier.  If you want to use it as a column name then you would need to wrap it in brackets when using it any SQL code, e.g. your ORDER BY expression.

Comment: I should have mentioned that is does sort this column singularly fine. I just need to sort by % then by W, then by High.

Comment: @Plutonix My question was about why the data I have already created as a table is not being displayed when bound to the DataGridView object, not looking for an alternative to what I have already done, but your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, with a bit of endeavour, I've managed to figure it out - the data IS there - but because I already had columns added in the object on the form, the program has tacked them on the end of those! I scrolled across out of curiosity and there they are.

[image]

Maybe this will be of some use to anyone else attempting a multi-column sort with a DataGridView object - my original code is sound, but make sure you haven't added any columns on the form (object properties).

As you can see from the image below, it's sorted by % and then W, and then High as a tiebreaker. Happy days

[image]